# How can I get the terminal opened in the same working directory it was closed in?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I want the bash terminal to be opened in the same directory it was closed in. In case of multiple terminals running and being closed. The new opened terminal would start at the working directory that last one was closed. My guess is I would somehow save PWD after closing and then retrieve it in .bashrc script. But I dont know how to automaticaly save PWD when terminal is closing.

Comment: This won't scale; it is only useful if you commit to never opening more than one terminal. The Mac Bash configuration has a session saving feature which scales to multiple terminal windows, but it is nontrivial, and IIRC depends on support from the Mac desktop platform.

Comment: I dont usualy need more then one terminal, Im using it to work with git mostly and its annoying to navigate my terminal to my project everytime I turn on a computer.

Comment: To scale it, some kind of stack could be implemented and a path to working directory would be pushed every time a terminal closes and popped every time a new terminal opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution:

In your `~/.bash_logout` add the following line in the end:

```
echo "BASH_LAST_DIR=$PWD" > ~/.bash_lastdir
```

In your `~/.bash_profile` add the following lines in the end:

```
if [[ -f ~/.bash_lastdir ]]; then
    source ~/.bash_lastdir
    cd $BASH_LAST_DIR
fi
```

That will do the job.

Finally, for easy of use, here is a `copy & paste` command to set that automatically for you:

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.bash_logout
echo "BASH_LAST_DIR=\$PWD" > ~/.bash_lastdir
EOF
cat << EOF >> ~/.bash_profile
if [[ -f ~/.bash_lastdir ]]; then
    source ~/.bash_lastdir
    cd \$BASH_LAST_DIR
fi
EOF
```

Just copy and paste on your terminal and you're all set.

Comment: Thanks for solution, works fine if I close the terminal by running `exit` command but not when I click on the cross button in the upper right corner. Any ideas how to solve  that?. I am using linux subsystem for windows so it might work differently here.

Comment: Unfortunately no. There is no easy way to handle that case.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so.. I did a little workaround and binded exit to my escape key by running `echo '"\e":"exit\n"' >> ~/.inputrc` and that works fine for me :)

Comment: what about auto issuing "cd -"?

Comment: Anyway to do this on Windows? Using Windows Terminal possible? xD

Comment: None that I know. Windows Terminal is uncharted territory to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your .bashrc

```
cd $LAST_WORKING_DIRECTORY
```

where last_working_directory is the last working directory you can save as a new environmental variable in .bashrc
This variable you must modify when you close your terminal

```
export LAST_WORKING_DIRECTORY="$pwd"
```

Comment: This will probably not work since the environment is destroyed (and the content of the variable is lost) when the bash session is finished. You need to save that in a file somewhere in your home directory, for example. ```.bash_logout``` is the file where you can implement something like that.

Comment: i suggest an enviromental variable saved in .bashrc,named $LAST_WORKING_DIRECTORY just like the $PATH. This variable will be updated every time a bash shell session ends

Comment: But even the syntax to set an environment variable is not right. You need to edit your answer and say the right thing to have that as solution.

Comment: I edited the my answer to a correct one. Thank you for noticing accdias

Comment: I don't think `export` is necessary or useful here. The purpose of `export` is to expose the variable to subprocesses, but clearly you don't want to run any subprocesses which actually use this variable.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`:

```
# start shell in last working directory used before exiting shell
if [[ -f ~/.bash_lastdir ]]; then
    source ~/.bash_lastdir
    cd $BASH_LAST_DIR
fi
```

```
# run when bash exits, save last working directory before exiting shell
exit_shell() {

    echo "BASH_LAST_DIR=$PWD" > ~/.bash_lastdir

}
trap exit_shell EXIT
```